# Nginx conf template not working with dokku

Tags: nginx, docker, dokku

I am stuck with the following nginx conf template:

```
# Special characters - dollar signs, spaces inside of quotes, etc. -
# should be escaped with a single backslash or can cause deploy failures.

server {
    listen      [::]:80;
    listen      80;
    server_name $NOSSL_SERVER_NAME;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/${APP}-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/${APP}-error.log;

    # set a custom header for requests
    # add_header X-Served-By www-ec2-01;

    location    / {
      proxy_pass  http://$APP;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host \$http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port \$server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Request-Start \$msec;
    }

    include $DOKKU_ROOT/$APP/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;

    # Proxy download 
    location ~* ^/internal_redirect/(.*?)/(.*) {
    # Do not allow people to mess with this location directly
    # Only internal redirects are allowed
    internal;

    # Location-specific logging
    access_log logs/internal_redirect.access.log main;
    error_log logs/internal_redirect.error.log warn;

    # Extract download url from the request
    set $download_uri \$2;
    set $download_host \$1;

    # Compose download url
    set $download_url http://\$download_host/\$download_uri;

    # Set download request headers
    proxy_set_header Host \$download_host;
    proxy_set_header Authorization '';

    # The next two lines could be used if your storage 
    # backend does not support Content-Disposition 
    # headers used to specify file name browsers use 
    # when save content to the disk
    proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="\$args"';

    # Do not touch local disks when proxying 
    # content to clients
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    # Download the file and send it to client
    proxy_pass \$download_url;
  }
}
```

The dokku docs tell me to escape '$' with a single \, so I did that.

Can a nginx wiz tell a nginx n00b what is wrong with the above template?

Dokku outputs the following error:

```
remote: nginx: [emerg] unknown log format "main" in /home/dokku/everseller/nginx.conf:117
remote: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
access_log logs/internal_redirect.access.log main;
```

assumes that there is a `log_format` directive which specifies a `main` format. By default `nginx` provides a `combined` format.

Either replace the above line with:

```
access_log logs/internal_redirect.access.log combined;
```

Or define a `log_format main`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks! Made the edit. Now I have a different error: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "set" directive in /home/dokku/everseller/nginx.conf:117. Whats a n00b to do? :-)

Comment: @Corstiaan You have some unescaped `$` in your `set` directives.

Comment: We're getting somewhere :-). However, no I get this error: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header" directive in /home/dokku/everseller/nginx.conf:96. Which call to proxy_set_header do you suspect is the culprit?